# Installing Sitecore 9(XP0) on premise with Amazon RDS for SQL Server

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup Sitecore 9(XP0) on premise with the SQL Server running on Amazon RDS for SQL Server.
Unfortunately it fails when running the scripts to setup the databases:
[image]

Is there anyone who had success setting up Sitecore 9 against an SQL in Amazon RDS?
Any tips on how to get the scripts working?

Thx, 
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least I've not heard of a way.

What you can do, is to set up the databases on a local MS SQL Server, and then use [SQL Database Migration Wizard](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-migrate-to-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-using-transactional-replication/) to move the databases onto Amazon RDS.

A few links to step by step guides:

- [SITECORE DATABASE DEPLOYMENT TO AMAZON RDS SQL](https://www.oshyn.com/blogs/2013/march/sitecore-database-deployment-to-amazon-rds-sql)
- [Sitecore Databases in Amazon RDS](https://www.symsoftsolutions.com/blog/2016/09/01/sitecore-databases-in-amazon-rds/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible have done it. I had a few issues with SQL commands which return an error because a setting cannot be updated through SQL in RDS, but instead should be updated in the parameter group. I made a small change to the SQL included in webdeploy packages for this. Some more details about this can be found in my [blog](https://jeroen-de-groot.com/2018/07/19/deploying-sitecore-9-in-aws-rds/) 
As mentioned in a different answer another option is to first install DBs in MS SQL and then move over.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some SC9 AWS setups, but have not used RDS as I don't believe it is officially supported by Sitecore. I would encourage you to reach out to Sitecore to make sure they will support your solution should you have the need.

In doing my own research and having bookmarked many topics, I did find this:

https://jeroen-de-groot.com/2018/07/19/deploying-sitecore-9-in-aws-rds/

Where I think this might be helpful to you is that it specifically addresses some database errors and its fairly recent (July 2018). Maybe this will help?